Calculating the world position of a 2d Qrcode in React-Three XR
I'm currently experimenting the React Three XR library combined with React Three Fiber for interacting with objects in an AR / XR web application.
Also, I'm using React Qr Scanner (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-scanner) for scanning a Qr Code.
What I intend to do is to scan a Qr Code with my phone and placing an object (here, a mesh, an orange box precisely) over it. Sadly, the box still shows way outside the zone of the Qr Code, always on the left, outside the viewport of the phone.
Here is the code I implemented.
Note: I'm kind of a newbie in the 3d world, further more applied to AR, I understand the vectors and the normalizing concepts, but I'm not in an advanced state.
Here is some part of my App.jsx.

The import section

import { ARButton, XR, useHitTest } from '@react-three/xr'
import { Canvas, extend, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { BoxGeometry, Vector3 } from 'three';
import QrScanner from 'react-qr-scanner';


The App function section

function App() {
  // 4 Corners (x,y) of the detected QrCode
  const [qrCodeCorners, setQrCodeCorners] = useState(null);

  // Got QrCode content ?
  const [qrCodeScanned, setQrCodeScanned] = useState(false);
  
  // Option to use the rear camera for scanning
  const constraints = {
    video: { facingMode: 'environment' }
  };

  // Handle the QrCode data scanned
  const handleQRCodeScan = (data) => {
    if(data) {      
      setQrCodeScanned(true);
      // Here, the data retrieved by the Qr Scanner module is an array of 4 objects containing each
      // the Vector2 coordinates of a corner
      setQrCodeCorners(data.resultPoints);
    }      
  };

  // This component represents the AR Session with the ARButton and my CustomMesh component on the
  // XR canvas. Need to add the option feature "dom-overlay" else the camera is not showing up
  const AROverlay = ({ corners }) => {

    return (
      <>
        <ARButton  sessionInit={{ requiredFeatures: ['hit-test'], optionalFeatures: [
          "dom-overlay",
        ],
        domOverlay: { root: document.body } }}/>
        <Canvas>
          <XR>
            <CustomMesh corners={corners} />
          </XR>
        </Canvas>
      </>
    );
  };

 // This component contains the logic for the mesh placement over the QrCode
 const CustomMesh = ({corners}) => {
    const { camera } = useThree();
    const [qrCodePosition, setQrCodePosition] = useState(new Vector3());
    const [qrCorners, setQrCorners] = useState(corners);

    // If the corners or the camera change, we update the position
    useEffect(() => {     
      convertTo3D(qrCorners);
    }, [qrCorners, camera]);

    const convertTo3D = (corners) => {
      // Calculate the center of the QR code in 2D screen space
      const centerX = (corners[0].x + corners[1].x + corners[2].x + corners[3].x) / 4;
      const centerY = (corners[0].y + corners[1].y + corners[2].y + corners[3].y) / 4;

      console.log(`Center X: ${centerX}, Center Y: ${centerY}`);

      // Normalize the Vector2 space coordinates
      const nX= (centerX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      const xY= -(centerY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

      console.log(`nX: ${nX}, nY: ${nY}`);

      // Create a Vector3 with a 0.5 z
      const screenPosition = new Vector3(nX, nY, 0.5);

      // Threejs doc: "Projects this vector from the camera's normalized device coordinate (NDC)
      // space into world space".
      screenPosition.unproject(camera);

      console.log(`Screen Position (unprojected): ${screenPosition.x}, ${screenPosition.y}, ${screenPosition.z}`);

      // Calculate the direction from the camera to the previous unprojected screenposition
      const direction = screenPosition.sub(camera.position).normalize();

      console.log(`Direction Vector: ${direction.x}, ${direction.y}, ${direction.z}`);

      // Calculate the distance from the camera to the point on the z = 0 plane
      // I assume the QR code lies on the z = 0 plane in the world space
      const distance = -camera.position.z / direction.z;

      console.log(`Distance: ${distance}`);

      // Calculate the world position by multiplying the direction with the distance
      // Here, we should (?) have the good world position
      const worldPosition = camera.position.clone().add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance));

      console.log(`World Position: ${worldPosition.x}, ${worldPosition.y}, ${worldPosition.z}`);

      // Set the position state to the calculated world position
      setQrCodePosition(worldPosition);
    };

    return ( <mesh position={qrCodePosition}>
      <boxGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial color='orange' />
    </mesh>)
  }

 // Finally, the return of all the render
 return (
    <>
      {/** QrCode detection ? */}
      {!qrCodeScanned && (
        <QrScanner
          delay={500}
          constraints={constraints} 
          onScan={(r) => {
            handleQRCodeScan(r);
          }  
          }
          onError={(e) => console.log(e)} />
      )}
    
      {/** QrCode Scanned ? */}
      {qrCodeScanned && (               
          <AROverlay corners={qrCodeCorners} />        
      )}     
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Thanks for your help and maybe explanations, I am missing something but I don't know what :).
